# How to return component only when firebaseAuthIsReady

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I decided to make component "reduxStore" (it is toplevel hoc in my project), where i'm creating a global store and make some config, including firebase middleware.

This is the code of component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

//Firebase
import {reduxFirestore, getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'
import {reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from '../config/fbConfig'

//RootReducer
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {attachAuthIsReady: true})
  )
);

const reduxStore = props => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {props.children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

store.firebaseAuthIsRady.then( () => {

})

export default reduxStore
```

As you can see, reduxStore wrapping my app in index.js:

```
const app = (
  <ReduxStore>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </ReduxStore>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("cardbox"))
```

The question is, how to apply **store.firebaseAuthIsReady** inside of reduxStore component, cause i want to render Auth or Layout components inside of App component in case user logged in or not. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you should move

```
store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then( () => {

})
```

to wrap

```
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("cardbox"))
```

in other words -

```
store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then( () => {
    ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("cardbox"))
})
```